# Geolocation coords not passing from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, geolocation

Been having a lot of dificulties to send geolocation data to php for store after in mysql. Searching and getting support has achieved a lot but still doesn't see the coords of the users in page.

Here the code.

1.code from `template-maps.php`:

```
var pos;
var posZae = function(pos){
                    return {
                            coords: {
                                latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                                longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                                accuracy: pos.coords.accuracy.toFixed()
                            },
                            timestamp: pos.timestamp
                    }
            };
var netPOS;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
        map.setCenter(pos);
        var netPOS = JSON.stringify(posZae(position));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  { 'pos' : pos},
            url: '/wp-content/themes/honolulu/template-userslocation.php'
        });
    },
    function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
};
```

it should send the data to `template-userslocation.php`where I have this code:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Template Name: template-userslocation
    */

    $lat = isset($_POST['pos']['lat']) ? $_POST['pos']['lat'] : null;
    $lng = isset($_POST['pos']['lng']) ? $_POST['pos']['lng'] : null;
?>
```

I get no ERROR, but if I charge the page there is no data. Nothing in the page and in the console.

---

Solved:

The problem is that it is being made in Wordpress and Wordpress has his own way to handle AJAX.

[Here the info](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2

I have no idea about any WordPress plugins or PHP. Does the lat/lng appear on the network/at the server? Anyway try this: -

```
var posZae = function(pos){
                    return {
                                lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                                lng: pos.coords.longitude,
                    }
            };
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = posZae(position);
        var netPOS = JSON.stringify(pos);
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
        map.setCenter(pos);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  { 'pos' : netPos},
            url: '/wp-content/themes/honolulu/template-userslocation.php'
        });
    },
    function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
};
```

EDIT 1

OK would this ring any bells of familiarity with you?

```
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
        map.setCenter(pos);
        var netPOS = JSON.stringify(pos4Net(position));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data:  { 'pos' : netPOS},
            url: '/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php'
        });
```

ORIGINAL POST:

Not sure where you "pos" is declared. Maybe localizing it with VAR will help instantiate it?

I've had the same/similar problem with the nature of the position object and call the following before trying to transmit it over the network: -

```
    var pos4Net = 
    function(pos)
    {
        return {
            coords: {
                latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                accuracy: pos.coords.accuracy.toFixed()
            },
            timestamp: pos.timestamp
        }
    }
```

So `var yourPos = pos4Net(position)`

Comment: mmmm, thank you, but not sure if that would be the problem.

Comment: Can't say for sure but IIRC the spec explains the problem. It might not be your issue but to set pos = position and try to JSON.stringify(pos) simply won't work. You must instantiate an alternative object as opposed to a simple reference. Sounds strange but trust me.

Comment: Thank you but I reading and searching and I don't understand the code that you send me. It's like an example that has nothing to do with mine. What you mean with `var yourPos = pos4Net(position)`; you even haven't position parameter.

Comment: Jesus Christ, It's exactly like mine! Anyway, it seems I have another extra problem and it is that it's inside Wordpress, so a lot of my problem was that it only can work using Wordpress Core.

Comment: Hi Ceasar, I am not a religious zealot but I much prefer profanity which I use regularly as opposed to taking the Lord's name in vain! We're all adults. Swear words are part of the vernacular and I'm up for it. But Christians just seem to be the only demographic that are open to abuse and I've had enough Cheers.

Comment: Well, after many tries it still doesn't work... Added Wordpress Core in a plugin to pass AJAX correctly and it seems fine. The problem is still with `pos`. Here the notice: `Notice: Undefined index: pos in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/zaeplug-userslocation/zaeplug-userslocation.php on line 22 NULL` Thank you pagan @McMurphy!

Answer (score 0):

> there is no data. Nothing in the page and in the console.

---

Your PHP code copies the POSTed data into a couple of variables. That is all.

It doesn't output anything. It doesn't use the variables for anything.

It just stores in the data in variables, then exits (which destroys the variables because they only exist for the lifetime of the program execution).

You need to do something with the data.

You could just output it straight back:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/plain"); echo $lat; echo $lng; ?>
```

… which isn't very useful, but serves as a demonstration.

---

Your JavaScript does nothing with the response.

(The response, as mentioned above, doesn't contain anything, so you need to fix the PHP first).

You have no success handler in your JavaScript, so when the browser gets the response, your code doesn't do anything with it. This is why nothing is shown in the browser.

```
    url: '/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php'
}).done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

… would show the results in the browser's developer tools console.

Comment: Thank you for your time. written to get the data in the console I still get nothing. Wrote the php code in the template where it should show the data and get two error notices: `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: lat in <b>/home/hooct781/public_html/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: lng in <b>/home/hooct781/public_html/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />`

Comment: @Caesar — You define `$lng` on line 7 of the PHP you showed us. Why are you trying to read it on line 5?

Comment: Ooops, true. But still it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: @Caesar — Then I can't reproduce the problem. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e51e3f9c24b136d36edd5082ca070da works for me.

Comment: I think that there should be some problem with sending AJAX  the data

Answer (score 0):

first console your lat. and lang. to check if you get any result then use the following code in ajax

```
data:  { 'lang' : coordinates , 'lat': coordinate},
```

then use $_POST['lant'] and $_POST['lang'] in destination file

Comment: Do you mean like this? ` console.log(pos.lat, pos.lng);` Have written after the AJAX code and get `Uncaught ReferenceError: coordinates is not defined` Any suggestions? thanx.

Comment: console.log(position.coords.latitude) at the beginning of the function before you initialize pos  variable and share your result

Comment: Well, that is komish, I get `(index):402 Uncaught ReferenceError: coordinates is not defined` but it should not be a problem because the infoWindow displays in the map with right coords from the user.

Answer (score -1):

The ajax function is sending `pos` which is an object but you are using array notation within the php script to access the lat/lng.

Perhaps if you did

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { lat:pos.lat, lng:pos.lng },
    url: '/wp-content/themes/atripby/template-userslocation.php'
});
```

You could then, in the PHP, try

```
$lat=!empty( $_POST['lat'] ) ? $_POST['lat'] : null;
$lng=!empty( $_POST['lng'] ) ? $_POST['lng'] : null;
```

Comment: PHP can handle the nested data structure in the question just fine.

Comment: mmm nothing, still all empty.

Comment: @Quentin ~ just did a quick mock up to test your assertion and it does not yield the correct response

Comment: @RamRaider — https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e51e3f9c24b136d36edd5082ca070da — My quick mockup works perfectly.

Comment: So, it seems that is the pos variable that isn't sending the coords?

Comment: @Quentin - I thought it might be a factor of the PHP version as no doubt you are on v7 whereas I still have 5.3.2 but just tested your code almost verbatim and ... it worked. I can only conclude that jQuery must do some trickery on the data that does not happen when using the vanilla XMLHttpRequest and no jQuery. 

https://gist.github.com/RamRaider/5635893e562d083f8010413d3bc6a08a

Comment: @RamRaider — Well yes. jQuery formats the data according to PHP's extended application/x-www-form-urlencoded stytax.

Comment: I did not know that, not using jQuery so my bad!